# Start a desktop program from MVC app using site on server n domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, iis

I've searched for solutions for this question everywhere. They all say it's not possible. I know MVC is hosted server-side so Process.Start will affect the server and not the client.

Is there anyway I can still configure the site or the client or the servers to open a desktopprogram or file on the client when the user clicks a button?

Thanks!

Comment: https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2022/01/20/getting-started-url-protocol-handlers-microsoft-edge/

Comment: In addition to what Crowcoder pointed out above, another option is to have your users download an app that sits and waits for some sort of notification that it should launch an app. Or in corporate environments where your server might have admin privileges on a user's machine, you can use tools like PowerShell and/or SSH to connect to the user's machine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, out of the blue, it rather hard for YOU to decide to run software on MY computer, right?

I mean, I might want to go view some cute cat pictures on your web site. However, while I am doing that, I doubt that security settings will THEN let you launch my banking applcation. Or how about you go rummage around on my computer, and grab files called passwords, or how about some files called banking information.

As you can see, the idea that since I decide to visit YOUR web site, you NOW going to start launching and running software on my computer? If this was easy, or even possible, then no sane person would EVER use the internet, since then you could at at will run software on my computer - such a possibility would make the internet oh so dangerous to use, and in fact so much so, that no one with a functional brain would ever risk using the internet again, would they?

So, as long as you are 100% clear that you searching for a way to launch and run software on my computer - such as accounting systems, banking systems, and that I would be insane enough to adopt a browser setup in which YOU can run any old software on MY computer?

No problem at all - but you want to at least be trained from the school of abused farm animals as to what you asking for here.

Note that you might be able to convince the users of that web site to eliminate or turn off any browser security, but then all of those users would indeed have a very vulnerable setup, and the resulting security issues would no doubt be deemed un-acceptable to any IT department.